# How do I fix an ioreg Error In My Python App Code?

Tags: python, ipad, error-handling, io, plotly-dash

I am getting the following error message when I run the code for my dash app on Pyto on an iPad. Everything else appears to be working fine, but I can't figure out the solution to this error. I have io imported and image files are going through a standard base 64 function to encode them as follows.

```
def b64_image(image_file):
encoded = base64.b64encode(open(image_file, 'rb').read())
return 'data:image/png;base64,{}'.format(encoded.decode())
```

In the traceback, it only seems to be throwing warning messages for the image file, but it is having no problem with the CSV and .db files. If anyone has any insight it would be greatly appreciated.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpuAd.jpg)

I think that it is an issue with the paths, but the paths are correct so bI can't figure out what to do next.

Comment: What is the type of image_file that you are opening? .jpg .png? Also it could be that you are passing something wrong to image_file. Could you double check that image_file is valid?

Comment: Hey Jason, they are .png files and the are passed in correctly because the same code works fine when run through VSCode on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Your traceback is not actually indicating a problem with this function. Its a warning that you did not close the images.

Consider:

```
def b64_image(image_file):
     with open(image_file,'rb') as image_data:

          encoded = base64.b64encode(image_data.read())
     return 'data:image/png;base64,{}'.format(encoded.decode())
```

Just put an answer so you can fix the 'not a problem' code section. A quick search implies that something is wrong with a call to ioreg.